# Protections against spikes in the design of AC and DC electronics?

Tags: voltage, dc, ac

Assuming that you are focusing on the choice that will give the best protection against spikes, would you go for an AC or a DC powered piece of electronics? Could you explain why and if this is your choice only in some given intervals in input (like only in X to Y Volts from a maximum of Z volts of tolerance)?

For example, an electrical engine that is out in the open and subject to bad weather (lightning) should be powered by...?

---

***EDIT:***

Following the clarification in the comments below, I would like to limit the discussion to devices and hardware that are used in aviation or that have similar properties and applications, like being able to function properly even without a ground connection.

Comment: Why are you asking? A specific application you have in mind, or something more general like ... homework?

Comment: @BrianDrummond mostly related to some bits of information that I got from some aviation documentaries . In the aviation business electrical engines are quite popular and I would like to know the answer to my original question just because I'm curious .

Comment: That was an important detail missing from the Q : aviation is different from most situations; it's harder to connect something to ground!

Comment: @BrianDrummond well, you are right, my bad, I'll edit this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper circuit protection can be designed into just about any kind of power supply. But absolute control of all transients is only really possible when you have control of the power source, whatever that is. Double conversion power supplies, like you might find in a high end UPS, use this kind of concept. Old school large scale systems use a motor-generator - it's literally a motor and a generator built into the same machine. This provides isolation, and gives you the flexibility to choose AC or DC in whatever configuration you like, but it's expensive to build and not incredibly efficient. More modern ones integrate a big flywheel to give a few seconds of ride-through in case the system blinks, and some really high end ones ALSO have a built in generator. All design decisions have trade offs; isolation, redundancy and capacity come at the cost of money, complexity,  and waste heat, in no particular order.

And to be perfectly clear, a direct lightning strike will destroy basically anything it passes through or by; aircraft survive because the outer envelope of the craft forms a Faraday cage. It only usually works. The real defense the aircraft has is not being grounded, preventing a catastrophic flow of current. Grounded systems have to rely on a network of large copper conductors to distribute the current flow in the hopes that they don't  melt, but it doesn't always stop things from exploding.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest AC because odds are that the "engine" is powered through a transformer of sorts, thus removing your connection to your source of energy. Sure, if lightning strikes the "engine" everything connected to it will be destroyed, but the energy source won't be affected as long as there is proper grounding. The transformer should provide adequate isolation and providing the circuit with an easier path to ground should protect your "source". AC also has the added benefit of being way more efficient for driving electric motors ("engines").